# How are posts added dynamically in news feed in Facebook's android app?

Tags: android, facebook, layout

In the news feed of the Android app of Facebook, the posts (I am talking about the one single box with the post text, like comment and share button) are added dynamically, that is as more posts are fetched from the server, more of such posts/boxes are created in the app. I want to create such sort of a news feed for my app.

My question is, how are such posts/boxes created in the app, like are these all items of a single ListView which has been custom defined, or are they created by adding Linear Layouts through java code which then inflate the standard XML created for a post.

Pardon me if the details I provided weren't so good in description technically, I am new to android.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a ListView with a custom adapter. Then, you will use a onScrollListener. When you sense a scroll at the bottom of the ListView, you will fetch new data from the server and add it to the ListView. As for the layout, each "item" is a row in the ListView and you can customize that how you want.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, facebook is not pure native app. It is  [hybrid- mobile  app](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/12/native-vs-mobile-web-vs-hybrid-applications.html) which means it has mixed implementation of web based technologies and native features. ( Look up for phone gap , corodova and IBM worklight to learn more about hybrid app if you don't know about it). So it is not necessary that those features you mentioned are implemented explicitly using native language. Since most of the features were developed by Facebook for the browser before going for mobile platform, I believe those features are still web based (HTML5, PHP, ajax) even for iphone and android. It is just wrapped in app container ( which gives them app like looks and the access to native features like pure native app can have including push notifications, gps access, camera access etc )for targeted platform and published in play store or app market.

But even if it was pure native, you can customize your listview to your desired looks and implement the adapter as per your need like the user @user1282637 mentioned.